# How to get cops off your back in GTA2?

Tags: grand-theft-auto-2

How do you get the police to not chase you in GTA2? Do they automatically stop searching after you stay out of sight for a particular amount of time, or is there anything that needs to be done?

Comment: Have you tried asking them nicely?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you drive through a "Max Paynt" spray shop, your wanted level is gone for the cost of $5000. Second drive-in on the picture below.

[image: Car shop]

Comment: Note that this won't work with some cars. For example Police Cars.